# How to create a ContextMenu when the mouse button is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a code for a DataGrid that fire the right mouse button event, in particular:

```
private void Squadre_DataGrid_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            //Context menu

        }
    }
```

I want create a ContextMenu inside the condition, and associate for each item of the ContextMenu a method that will be executed if the item will be choose.
How to do this?

Comment: http://www.wpftutorial.net/ContextMenu.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can achieve that in XAML. Assuming you want to have a context menu for the rows of your DataGrid,  you can add the ContextMenu property to your DataGridRow, for example:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource theContextMenu}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Then add the context menu itself in the resource dictionary:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="theContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Menu Item 1" Click="menuItem1_Click">
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Menu Item 2" Click="menuItem2_Click">
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then write a click event handler for each menu item to execute your method:

```
private void menuItem1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // execute your method..
}

private void menuItem2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // execute your method..
}
```

Comment: very beatiful example, last question: If I want delete the row selected? In the menuItem2 method what code I must add? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on how you bind the `ItemsSource` of your DataGrid. 
IF, for example you bind it to a `List<MyObject>` called `myList`, you can remove the selected DataGrid row object from the list: `myList.Remove(myDataGrid.SelectedItem as MyObject);`. 
Then, refresh your DataGrid: `myDataGrid.Refresh();`. 
But again, it really depends on how you do the binding.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind datacontext content to a propertie and than fill It (propertie) in your Button event. Don't forget to set Update condition in Contextmenu binding (xaml)

Comment: Could you made an example for me?

Comment: I'll try :)
I see that you use code behind rather than MVVM, but it's no problem.
OK, first propertie with menu items

`private List<string> _menuItems;
pubilc List<string> MenuItems
{
  get {return _menuItem;}

  set { SetProperty(ref _menuItem,value)  }
}'

As you see above SetProperty give you autochecking for value change :)

Comment: Uhh to late to edit this comment. Look [here] (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/779264/Dynamically-Generating-Context-Menu-Items) its very good example. If you'll have more questions just write :)

Answer (score 0):

In my view the best form of work this out is adding an `ContextMenu` for each row of `DataGrid`, we can do it in the following way:

In the `XAML`, place in your `DataGrid` an listener to event `LoadingRow`:

```
<!-- resume version of declaration your DataGrid -->
<DataGrid x:Name="Squadre_DataGrid" LoadingRow="Squadre_DataGrid_LoadingRow" />
```

In the `CodeBehind`, come on add the `ContextMenu` for each row:

```
private void Squadre_DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
      ContextMenu _contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
      MenuItem mia = new MenuItem();//item 1
      MenuItem mib = new MenuItem();//item 2
      ....
      _contextMenu.Add(mia);
      _contextMenu.Add(mib);
      ....
      e.Row.ContextMenu = _contextMenu;//add context menu to row
}
```